# Аутентификация Django rest framework

Tags: python, django, reactjs, django-rest-framework, login

есть проблема. Я делаю апи для входа в акаунт на drf и jwt токен должен сохраняться в localStorage чтобы потом поместить его в хедер Authorization. Проблема в том что даже когда токен есть в хедерах request.user возвращает  AnonymousUser (фронт енд на реакте)

view для логина

```
class LoginAPI(views.APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.CustomUserAuthentication,)
    
    def post(self,request):
        email = request.data['email']
        password = request.data['password']

        user = services.user_email_selector(email=email)
    
        if not isinstance(user,Response):
            if not user.check_password(raw_password=password):
                raise exceptions.AuthenticationFailed("Invalid credentiels")
            
        else:
            return user

        token = services.create_token(user_id=user.id)
        resp = Response({
            'username': user.username,
            'email': user.email,
            'token': token
        })

        resp.set_cookie(key='jwt', value=token, httponly=True, samesite='Lax')

        return resp
```

services.user_email_selector и  services.create_token:

```
def user_email_selector(email: str) -> "CustomUser":
    try:
        user = CustomUser.objects.get(email=email)
    except CustomUser.DoesNotExist:
        return Response({'message': 'User does not exists'},status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
    
    return user

def create_token(user_id: int) -> str:
    payload = dict(
        id=user_id,
        exp=datetime.datetime.utcnow() + datetime.timedelta(hours=24),
        iat=datetime.datetime.utcnow(),
    )
    token = jwt.encode(payload, settings.JWT_SECRET, algorithm="HS256")

    return token
```

потом отправляеться запрос сюда:

```
class GetUserAPI(views.APIView):
    authentication_classes = (authentication.CustomUserAuthentication,)

    def get(self,request):
        if not isinstance(request.user,AnonymousUser):
            user_instanse = UserDataClass.from_instance(request.user)

            return Response({
                'email': user_instanse.email,
                'username': user_instanse.username,
                'ether_public_key': user_instanse.ether_public_key
            },status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response({'message': 'not authenticated'},status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

тут отправляется запрос в реакте:

```js
const axiosInstance = axios.create({
    baseURL: DOMAIN,
    headers: {
        'Authorization': localStorage.getItem('token')?Bearer ${localStorage.getItem('token')}:null
    }
})

axiosInstance.get('/api/auth/get_user/')
  .then((response) => {
    const user =  response.data
    console.log(user);
  })
```